# How can I successfully implement ngIf conditions

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to successfully implement some ngIf logic into my ionic app. 
I have currently got the current flow that you can see in the images below. 
The user types in a project title, and the next option appears, then the can select what type of media they want to upload. I've implemented NgIf conditions into this flow. However, When I want to give the user the option to go back and rename the title. I am having trouble getting my head around the logic.

When the user taps on the back button, I am finding it difficult to get the app to the previous state, where theres the input box for the title. I only can get back the next button.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Below is the code that I have tried,

HTML

```
 <ion-item *ngIf = "nextOptions == next" no-padding style ="text-align: center;" id="projectTitle" color="transparent">
          <ion-input [(ngModel)]="title" class="text-input" placeholder="Project Title"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
            <div style="text-align: center !important;" >
            <ion-button   *ngIf ="!title"  style="margin-top: 40%" color ="transparent">maybe later</ion-button>
            <ion-button  (click)="nextOption()" *ngIf = "title && !nextOptions"   style="margin-top: 40%"color ="transparent">next</ion-button>
          </div>
```

TS

```
nextOption() {
  this.nextOptions = "next"
}

backtoTitle() { 
  this.nextOptions = '';
}
```

Can someone please help, I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: is it the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf = "nextOptions == 'previous'">
 <ion-item no-padding style ="text-align: center;" id="projectTitle" color="transparent">
       <ion-input [(ngModel)]="title" class="text-input" placeholder="Project Title"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
            <div style="text-align: center !important;" >
            <ion-button   *ngIf ="!title"  style="margin-top: 40%" color ="transparent">maybe later</ion-button>
            <ion-button  (click)="nextOption()" *ngIf = "title && !nextOptions"   style="margin-top: 40%"color ="transparent">next</ion-button>
          </div>

</ng-container>
```

Be careful you have forgotten the '' in 'next' (and not like you *next*) in your *ngIf.

EDIT: It ts you do:

```
nextOption() {
  this.nextOptions = "next"
}

backtoTitle() { 
  this.nextOptions = "previous";
}
```

and now correct the code in this way:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf = "nextOptions == 'previous'">
```

your problem is easy to resolve, you take a variable and according when the user click you show html.

Comment: When I click on the 'back' button everything disappears now